# How are Hash Map values stored (in case the values are duplicates)?

Tags: java, collections, hashmap

Does a Java `HashMap` save duplicate values as unique or does it save them individually?

Let's imagine I have the following key-value pairs value:

```
A -> "a very long string...."
B -> "another very long string...."
C -> "the same very long string from A key.... (but not same string instance)"
```

Will it be saved as 3 keys and 3 values, or as 3 keys and 2 values (as value for `A` is exactly the same as value for `C`)

My concern is about sizing as the values I am going to save are quite big and make no sense duplicate them.

Comment: You can consider making `StringBuilder` instances of the strings and store them. That way you are storing the references only..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `HashMap` can contain duplicate values, so in your example there would be 3 keys and 3 values in the `Map`.

However, if you are concerned about large instances being stored multiple times as values in your `Map`, you should store references to the same instance.

For example:

```
String val = "a very long String............";
String val2 = "a second long String.........";
map.put(1,val);
map.put(2,val2);
map.put(3,val);
```

There are only two large `String` instances. The `Map` contains 3 references to those `String`s (two references to the first `String` and one reference to the second `String`), but references occupy a small amount of storage.

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't keep values, it holds references to values, so the problem boils down to the question "Are `"a very long string...."` and `"the same very long string from A key...."` the same object in memory?"

If they aren't compile-time constants and are obtained/constructed at runtime, they are different objects. String interning, along with [`String#intern`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#intern()), can help you here but has its limitations mentioned by @bratkartoffel.

[What is Java String interning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10578984/what-is-java-string-interning)
[When should we use intern method of String on String literals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1855170/when-should-we-use-intern-method-of-string-on-string-literals)
[Performance penalty of String.intern()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10624232/performance-penalty-of-string-intern)

Comment: Please, do NOT use intern() on very large string. This will quickly lead to problems as the instances are saved in a separate space (Permanent Generation, not heap). That space is limited and intended for the classes, methods and internal JVM stuff.

Answer (score 2):

But this *does not concern* `HashMap`, I mean it is not specific to it. Having a value as a `String` implies two other different things too - such as String interning or the fact that `String`s are immutable. Also a `HashMap` does not *copy* the value (whatever that might mean), it only stores references to other objects - what you do with those Objects is entirely up to you. If you change an Object outside of the `HashMap` and then query that `Map` against that particular associated key, you will see the update.

Answer (score 1):

The Java `HashMap` does not allow duplicate keys, but it does allow duplicate values. So it would save them as 3 keys and 3 values.

In order for it to not save the value twice, you would have to check for it (for example by using the `.containsValue()` method).

Comment: I suppose there is no `contains()` method declared in `Map`

Comment: Take your pick from ```containsKey()``` and ```containsValue()```.